# jTable. row sorting() from text file

Tags: java, sorting, netbeans, jtable

I have a problem regarding sorting in `jTable1` i looked at few already asked questions about this problem in this forum but no answer seem to work for me, how can i set up numerical sequence that is working in a regular order instead of going 1, 10, 11...2, 20, 21,... 3,.. and etc. How can i modify this piece of code `jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);` since it doesn't seem to be working properly. Here is the current code I am using.

```
try {
        FileReader fR = new FileReader("table.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fR);
        String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
        String[] columnsName = firstLine.split(",");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
        Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++)
        {
            String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow = line.split("/");
            model.addRow(dataRow);

        }
                    jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Convert the sequence to a numerical value, `String` is been sorted based on it's textual representation, which is a very common issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MadProgrammer left a comment that is the correct answer. You need to insert a row of numerical values (ie - Integer[], Float[], Double[], etc.) as opposed to the String[] you're using right now.

For an example on how to make this conversion, here's how to convert a String[] into an Integer[] using some of your code as a starting point

```
String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
String[] dataRow = line.split("/");
int dataRowLength = dataRow.length;
Integer[] dataRowIntegers = new Integer[dataRowLength];
for(int i = 0; i < dataRowLength; i++){
    dataRowIntegers[i] = Integer.valueOf(dataRow[i]);
}
model.addRow(dataRowIntegers);
```

Hope this helps!